# Race condition when going directly secured page

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am running into a race condition when an unknown user is trying to access a secured page.

Iron-Router code:

```
function secured() {
    if ( Meteor.user() == null ) {
        Meteor.loginWithLinkedin({
        },function (err){
            if(err){
                console.log("Error when login with LinkedIn."+JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        });
    }
}

Router.map(function () {this.route('customer_researchRequest', {
    before: secured,
    waitOn: waitOnHuman,
    path: '/research/request',
    template: 'customer_researchRequest',
    layoutTemplate: 'customer_requestLayout'
});});
```

On the server:

```
    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
        service: 'linkedin'
    });

    ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({... settings ...});
```

If the user goes directly to /research/request, there is a race condition.

1. before condition fires
2. (on client)ServiceConfiguration.configurations has no configuration
3. client has exception about no linkedin service defined.
4. server publishes the ServiceConfiguration.configurations to the client

At this point, my solution is to hard code in the clientId and other linkedin config information into the linkedin authentication code ( Yech ).

Is there a better more elegant/correct solution?

Update #1: My solution was to tweak the meteor-linkedin package so that it expects the linkedIn clientId as an option and does not depend on the ServiceConfiguration.configuration. This way the clientId is always available.

Comment: I assume your client is never expected to directly access that page but to use some other page, so a possible solution would be to generate some code that you supply with the request for that secured page. It would permit you to check for that code before you perform any other action, thus allowing you to redirect the client to another page, if the code is missing.

Comment: @Abrixas2 - "I assume your client is never expected to directly access that page..." : This is an INCORRECT assumption. We don't have a detected login page. The user is expected to be able to go directly to the page. Its just that if they do, the (accounts-linkedin) LinkedIn logon popup should happen.

Comment: "detected login page" --> "dedicated login page".

Comment: Bug filed : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1911

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution turns out to be my "hack" of creating a forked meteor-linkedin which accepts the client configuration in the login call.

We edited the meteor-linkedin so that the Meteor.loginWithLinkedIn() call supplied the linkedIn clientId.

Currently, Meteor's ServiceConfiguration is stored in a mongo table and needs to be published from the server to client. The clientId is essentially a static configuration variable that might as well be encoded into the client code. Just putting the linkedin clientId directly in the login code turns out to be infinitely more reliable and simpler.

Even if Meteor was to 'fix' the publishing race condition, we would stick with our solution: it is bulletproof and guaranteed to work. You can borrow our code our [meteor-linkedin](https://github.com/whalepath/meteor-linkedin) and [accounts-meteor-linkedin](https://github.com/whalepath/meteor-accounts-linkedin)

The meteor dev people [aren't planning on fixing the issue](http://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1911). I agree with this decision, it is much better to just have the (constant) client configuration on the client rather than being stored on the server and sent to the client.

Update: In the end for a variety of reasons, we almost entirely abandoning the meteor oauth code. The client-side centric approach with popup dialogs caused numerous problems. [I talk about some of the issues on the 1911 bug report](http://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1911). We ended up triggering the oauth code ourselves server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to address comment:

Maybe a different use of reactivity can help.  Set up a deferred redirect to customer_researchRequest, by first diverting the user, then bringing them up

A) Have secured() save the original destination path to the session.  Redirect to a page you allow without security (or a 'Loading...' page), to avoid your #3
B) when the login callback happens, save another flag to the session, indicating that #4 is no longer true
C) have a Deps.autorun redirect to the desired path when both flags become true.

Someone else may know a smarter way, (maybe waitOn should test for the config) but ...

Comment: Actually reactivity is causing the problem ( you can see it with the order of steps 3 and 4). ( see update)

Comment: Agreed: It would be best to have the waitOn a ServiceConfiguration topic: however, I couldn't find the topic that Meteor uses. In the end, hacking the meteor-linkedin package and hard coding the clientId was good enough and guaranteed to work.

Comment: To future googlers:  Setting up a deferred reactive login situation as I suggest above is perfectly valid and easy to do.  As, of course, is the self answer to rewrite things so they work the way one thinks about them.  I like to discover and work within the parameters of the supported environment.

Comment: To future googlers: Highly reliable solutions are preferred to elegance. If the race condition still exists you know the simple way to solve this. Always be aware that your manager/CEO is judging you on ability to execute. 10 minute solutions always better than 2 hour solutions.